# How to handle the non-js environment?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

Let say I have a web page, index, and have a button can login, when I click login, the webpage become the login page,.....
Here is what the web look like:

```
[     Banner      ]
[     Main        ]
[     Footer      ]
```

The site have 3 parts, Banner, Main and Footer. When user login, I change the main div to login, via an ajax call:

```
[     Banner      ]
[     Login       ]
[     Footer      ]
```

It works great, but if the NON-JS environment, I need to render the whole page. What should I do the best to handle it is the most common way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *'NON-JS environment'* means disabled or not supported javascript, use NOSCRIPT tag block.
See in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript), in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: There are better ways than `<noscript>`: Craete the markup in a way that it works without JavaScript and then add the extra-functionality via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work correctly without JS, you'll need to handle rendering without AJAX. Depending on your backend you could try to reroute to a new page containing the correct content after successful login.